# the error of Levels in factors of new data do not match original data in using R predict function

Tags: r

I am using R to build prediction model. However, the `predict` always gives me the error message such as

[image]

I know that it should be caused by some test feature levels are not included in the training feature levels. Since the feature matrix itself is big, and it is very hard to modify the feature levels one-by-one in the feature matrix of test data set. Is there a way to enforce the levels of feature items in the test data set to fit the existing levels of training feature items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of making a test variables have the same levels as a training variable:

```
test <- factor(LETTERS[1:5])
training <- factor(LETTERS[4:10])
levels(test)
#[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
```

Trying to replace a value where the level is not present:

```
test[2] <- training[5]
#Warning:
#  In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, 2, value = 5L) :
#  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

You can get around this by uniting the factor levels:

```
levels(test) <- union(levels(test), levels(training))
levels(test)
#[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J"
test
#[1] A B C D E
#Levels: A B C D E F G H I J
```

Now you can do the previous operation without warning:

```
test[2] <- training[5]
test
#[1] A H C D E
#Levels: A B C D E F G H I J
```

Most likely you can use a similar approach in your case, but I'm not sure about the exact structure of your data.